# how to disable facebook auto login in my application using new Facebook Javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am now using Facebook Javascript SDK for connecting my application through Facebook login. If new user coming to connect with my application, the user details will be saved in the database. If the user already exists, then the appropriate page will be shown to the user through Facebook login. Sometimes if I login in Facebook in new tab of browser, during that time I come to Facebook connecting page in my application, the Facebook login is automatically login into my application page. I want to login into my application only after click of the facebook login button.How to do?

```
        <div id="fb-root">
            </div>

            <script>
            //FB initialization
               window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                    FB.init({
                        appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                        channelUrl : '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', 
                        status     : true, 
                        cookie     : true 
                    });
        //Event to check status of the login status
                    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                            base_url = base_url + "&access_token=" + response.authResponse.accessToken + "&userId=" + response.authResponse.userID;
                            window.location.href = base_url;
                        }
                        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              FB.login();
            } else {
              FB.login();
            }
                    });

                };
// Load the SDK asynchronously
            (function (d) {
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', 
               ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
            } (document));


        <fb:login-button scope="email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_location"></fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what your problem is, but it sounds like your login function is firing on pageload as opposed to after a particular event, such as click.

If you wanted to bind the login function to clicks on an element with an id of 'login', then the following function (in jQuery) would work.

```
$(function() {
  $('#login').click(function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      // rest of function definition
    }, {scope: 'email'});
  });
});
```

And similarly, you might call `FB.logout()` after some other event.

Comment: Your code not working properly in mozilla firefox and IE. I have already written this type of code in my application. When I click login button, facebook login will be opened in side of the browser screen in mozilla firefox and IE. Chrome no problem. That is why I am using above code to show login pop up in center of the browser screen. If you have any idea, please tell me.